# strange result after division in c++

Tags: c++, division

I want to divide to variable like below. I found that when I divide `c` which is `double` and the value for example is `0.0137777887700191` to `10` the diff becomes `6.9533479143199673e-310`.

```
double diff = c /  static_cast<double>(10);
```

Why the results is like this. Can you help me please.

a part of code is like this:

```
double c = uniform(0,(nextac0PktExpir->getArrivalTime() - simTime()).dbl());
double diff = c / 10.0;
```

Comment: why not use 10.0 instead of a `static_cast`?

Comment: yes i can. they are the same. but the problem is not that.

Comment: i think the double cast is unnecessary since it will be performed implicitly

Comment: it has the same behaviour with 10.0 ? Are you sure about your values for c and diff ?

Comment: Be sure that c is actually 0.0134. Be sure to print correctly your diff variable. If you print c do you get 0.0134 in the stdout?

Comment: yes i check my code with debugger and i found these numbers for these two parameters. and the results doesn't depend on way of casting.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: the full code is like 1000 lines code or more.

Comment: this _can't_ be the code which causes the bug. You need to show us an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: At least the minimum working example?

Comment: the point is, if you compile and run a minimal example like Dipika's answer - then your bug will very likely disappear.  It must be something outside of the code you've listed (something else modifiying c / diff, or values showing up strangely in your debugger?).  What if you write the values out to std::cout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  double c(0.0134);
  double diff;
  std::cout << diff << std::endl;
  diff = c /10.0;
  std::cout << diff;

  return 0;
}
```

With g++ it will print:

```
6.95322e-310    (or something similar...)
0.00134
```

You're probably checking the value of `diff` in the debugger before the assignment is performed.

Comment: thanks. I exactly do that. because it is a big code and i was debugging it in gbd and i found diff like 6.9533479143199673e-310 and i didn't find any other form.

Comment: how can I see the normal output in debugger?

Comment: You have to step over the assignment statement, then test the value of diff.

Answer (score 0):

This works For me. Its giving expected result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
 double c = 0.0134 ;
 double diff = c /10;
 cout << diff;
 return 0;
}
```